# A question regarding the SVD

Tags: svd

I just read this certifiable [tutorial](http://web.mit.edu/be.400/www/SVD/Singular_Value_Decomposition.htm) which is indeed informative:

However, I couldn't go further after the following sentence:

> The values of x1 and x2 are chosen such that the elements of the S are the square roots of the eigenvalues.

My question is how did they calculate $x_1$ and $x_2$? I cannot relate the  sentence above to the obtained values.

Comment: @Moo I am talking about that sentence and what follows it. What do you mean?

Comment: I already did that in addition to several other ones. However, I want to understand the highlighted sentence and what follows it. I know how to decompose a matrix in general, but I want to understand what was the intention of the author in that specific source.